# Moment.js : start of year of a current date is not what expected for other time zone than UTC

Tags: momentjs

I experienced difficulties with `Moment.js` when I try to use it for people who are in different timezone.

I want to get the first day of the current year.

```
console.log(moment().format())
// 2020-04-08T05:39:26-04:00

console.log(moment().startOf("year").format())
// 2019-12-31T19:00:00-04:00
```

I expected to have the start of the year for my timezone. It is not the case.
My zone has -4 hours offset with the UTC time. I don't even understand why the returned time is `2019-12-31T19:00:00` and not `2019-12-31T20:00:00` .

I tried to add to my time, the UTF offset, but with this difference of 5 hours instead of the 4 hours normally used, it is not even enough. I doubt too that it is a good practice.

My need is only to get the date (not the hours). Example: we are the `2020-04-08` and I want to return `2020-01-01`. I can extract the year and manually set first for day and month, but I am surprised how difficult it is to have it done with Moment.js.

Thanks for any clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the easy way to handle this case it not to use `startOf` at all.

With alternative libraries like `date-fns`, the problem is present as well.

But it works with `moment().dayOfYear(1)`.